# relation between server and client's transport in golang

Tags: sockets, http, go, server

I have both - a client and a server in **a one program**. With a function `func Get(url string) ([]byte, error)` i make tons of requests to **other** server and my server handles one per second request from **other** clients. The function for request is:

```
var transport = &http.Transport{}
func Get(url string) ([]byte, error) {
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    var client = &http.Client{
        Transport: transport,
        Timeout:   15 * time.Second,
    }

    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if resp != nil && resp.Body != nil {
        defer resp.Body.Close()
    }

    if err != nil {
        if resp != nil && resp.Body != nil {
            io.Copy(ioutil.Discard, resp.Body)
        }

        return nil, err
    }

    data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    return data, err
}
```

and the server is:

```
func homePage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprint(w, "Hello")
}

http.HandleFunc("/", homePage)
http.ListenAndServe(":9002", nil)
```

So, the question is - why **my** server start waiting, while **my** clients send all their requests to **other** server, before it start handling **other** client's request? What do i miss? CPU is ok, memory is ok, bandwidth is ok.

Comment: You need to show how you create and start your client and server.

Comment: The server and the clients runing inside difference goroutines, ie ```go StartMyClientsForUrl("http://example.com/")``` and ```go StartMyServer()```

Comment: You need to show more than what you have, because there's nothing here preventing an http.Server from accepting requests. Try to provide a [working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). (not related; check you client error first. The response isn't valid if there's an error, and the Body is guaranteed to be non-nil when there's no error.)

Comment: [It's "me"](https://play.golang.org/p/05ndaxlgiY), [It's "other server"](https://play.golang.org/p/-G6JS62CVX). For other clients you can use your browser.

Comment: First: there is no connection between a client's Transport and the server. Second: You probably should _reuse_ your client Transports instead of using a fresh one for each and every client GET request (I'd guess you are just running out of FDs). Third: maybe you could reformulate your question? I'm not sure I understand your question: E.g. what is waiting for what? How do you see something is "waiting"?

Comment: You're just exhausting file descriptors. You can't Dial 100,000 connections simultaneously, and once the process is out of FDs, the server can't accept any connections.

Comment: But, i'm reuse my transport. I create it only once, before any call ```Get(url string) ([]byte, error)``` would done. So, why i'm run into FD limit?

Comment: You're trying to make 100,000 connections concurrently, which would take 100,000 file descriptors (not counting any used in DNS resolution, etc.).

Comment: Anyway, we are talking of incomplete code fragments. Please provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)